# how to make "&nbsp;" word-wrap on chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

this is my code :

```
<div id="a" style="position:absolute;top:300px;width:100px;height:100px;background:red;color:black;word-wrap:break-word;">
    <div id='a2' contenteditable=true >
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

this code word-wrap in firefox , but in chrome  i cant word-wrap,

so how to make `&nbsp;` word-wrap on chrome  ?

thanks

Comment: "nbsp" stands for "non-breaking space", so it looks like you're trying to suck and blow at the same time. Could you describe the problem you're actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 10):

You make them word wrap like this:

```
 &nbsp;<wbr>&nbsp;<wbr>&nbsp;<wbr>&nbsp;<wbr>&nbsp;<wbr>
```

Answer (score 8):

`&nbsp;` creates a [non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). The purpose of a non-breaking space is to provide a space, while not counting as a place to break a line. (Which normal spaces are.)

Therefore, you cannot make them word-wrap, as they're designed to not do so. If you want word-wrapping, use normal spaces.

Comment: Yes, except that `&nbsp;` has more than one function. It also allows having more than one space in a row, in places where `white-space` property otherwise collapses multiple spaces into one. Forced disability to break on overflow is not something I can call desired functionality and should have been configurable. This is not directed at you, but since you are so about "it should be that way", here, have a different point of view.